# CSS of Blank Theme Does NOT Show My Edits - Why?

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

On Wordpress.org, I activated a BLANK theme by Chris Coyier.
I edit index.php and my changes are showing up on my website.  Fantastic.

I edit the existing style.css file but none of my edits are showing up.  Ugh.

I delete style.css and the website still works.  Why?
I repeat these steps with a different blank theme. Same issues.

Questions

1. Why am I unable to edit style.css of ANY blank theme? I am confused because I am able to edit style.css of Twentyfourteen theme.
2. If I delete style.css from the blank theme, the website still works and still shows the same CSS styling. How is this possible?
3. For blank themes, the stylesheet is called in header.php as

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />`

But for Twentyfourteen theme, I don't see any call for a stylesheet.

Why do regular themes not have a call for a stylesheet in header.php? Is this why I cannot edit style.css of blank themes?

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache (CTRL+F5)

Comment: YAY! This worked! Thank you C-link Nepal!!

Can you explain what the problem was? I want to understand what was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your browser is caching the CSS?

What happens when you use your browsers dev tools to check the CSS source.does that show your edits?

When you say "delete the CSS" do you get a missing resource error on the browser console?

If it does not, try force reloading your page.

Comment: I thought that was the issue. Browsers usually cache resources such as CSS and javascript files to save on bandwidth. Force reloading tells the browser to actually get the resources anew. Could you perhaps do me the pleasure of marking it answered then? ;)

Comment: Sure, just marked it. Kris, can you explain why editing CSS of blank themes require CTRL+F5 but ready-made themes such as Twentyfourteen display edited CSS with only F5? I'm afraid that once I put this website live, users will not see updates to my website because they won't know to force reload.

Comment: I ll check in an hour or so when I'm back behind my computer.